# Is there a way to get hash in URL in react-navigation/native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, amazon-cognito

I'm using "react-navigation" for my "react-native" frontend routing, and I have "Amazon Cognito" redirecting to my app with the path :

`/loginredirect#id_token=sometoken`

and I need a way for the frontend to read the "token" and act accordingly.

**But the issue is**, react-navigation seems to instantly change the route to the default route even though /loginredirect is a defined path for some route.

I need some way to get react-navigation to recognize the hash in the URL as a valid path and then grab that hash. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

React-navigation does not consider the url fragment "#" as a special character. Instead, it will literally try to compare the initial url with the path configured in config object. For instance, your app will open at the right screen if you configure the path for the screen to "/loginredirect#id_token=sometoken" instead of "/loginredirect" in the config object.

For react-navigation to open with path /loginredirect, you need to parse the linking URL by replacing the '#' by '?'. You can do it by using getInitialURL function when the app opens with a initial URL and subscribe function to listen to any linking URL when the app is open.

```js
    const prefixes = ['myapp://', 'https://myapp.com'];

    const config = {
      screens: {
        Login: 'loginredirect',
    };
    
    const parseUrl = (url) => {
      let parsedUrl = url;
      if (url.includes('#')) {
        parsedUrl = url.replace('#', '?');
      }
      return parsedUrl;
    };

    const getInitialURL = async () => {
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
    
      if (url != null) {
        return parseUrl(url);
      }
    
      return url;
    };
    
    const subscribe = (listener) => {
      const onReceiveURL = ({ url }) => {
        listener(parseUrl(url));
      };
      const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
    
      return () => {
        subscription.remove();
      };
    };
    
    const linking = {
      prefixes,
      config,
      getInitialURL,
      subscribe,
    };
    
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      ...
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Params will be available in the route.params of your screens